# ec2:DeleteNetworkInterface does not work

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

We have an iam role that looks like below:

```
{
       "Effect": "Deny",
       "Action": [
           "ec2:DeleteNetworkInterface"
       ],
       "Condition": {
           "StringLike": {
               "ec2:ResourceTag/Name": [
                   "krishnakumar*"
               ]
           }
       },
       "Resource": [
           "*"
       ]
 }
```

When I attach this to a user, I am able to delete all enis (does not matter if the eni tag name is krishnakumar-test. However when we change "StringLike" with "ForAllValues:StringLike", it does not allow me to delete any eni (both krishnakumar-test and test-eni). I have removed the "*" and tried but no luck

Can someone help me with why this is failing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `"ec2:DeleteNetworkInterface"` does not support resource level permissions. What this means is that you can only control it's use for all resources or no resources - it's either on or off and cannot be limited to a particular subset of resources.

Please see the [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/ec2-api-permissions.html#ec2-api-unsupported-resource-permissions) for clarification.

Comment: Thanks @mickzer, that's the answer I was looking for.